# Is it possible to share same global variable between javascript file and typescript file in angular project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular5

I am using a javascript library in angular 5 project.If I define a global variable in my .js file then what is the way to access that global variable from my .ts file??

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest approach, but you can always just define it on the `window` object in javascript and then inside Angular read out the same `window` object.

Or use `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` `setItem()`/`getItem()` for it but that will mean the value is retained between session or page refresh